# How could I create a custom textview which has specifed distance to its left when meet some characters,for instance ,like '@'

Tags: android

I don't know how to solve this issue,there are some strings needed to fill in the textview,"@Tony@Tom@James@Brown...",what I want to do is like following "@Tony  @Tom  @James  @Brown..." this will be displayed in the textview,the spacing is also specified,for example,"20dp" is the distance between '@Tony' and '@Tom'.I don't know how to create a textview likes above,I have a another question,when the content is out of range,the content should start from next line,so do I deal with this problem?Thank you anyone who gives an answer. If I didn't discribe this question in detail,forgive me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/2242 .

```
<com.apradanas.simplelinkabletext.LinkableEditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

---

```
// find username
Link linkUsername = new Link(Pattern.compile("(@\\w+)"))
                    .setUnderlined(false)
                    .setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#D00000"))
                    .setTextStyle(TextStyle.BOLD)
                    .setClickListener(new Link.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(String text) {
                            // do something
                        }
                    });
```

more information is available on the android arsenal page

Comment: thank you all the same,I reckon that I should use SpannableString,it's very useful for TextView operation